# How can I get the translation of taxonomy term with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, drupal-6

With drupal php api it's easy with `i18nstrings_string("taxonomy:term:$term_id:name");` but how can I get with javascript?

Comment: Since you can do it with PHP, just make a simple api for javascript. So a page called "translate.php?term=term" and then have php do the function and echo it back.

Comment: I don't want to make ajax requests because I have over than 100 similar data to output and to make a ajax request for each one it's a performance cost.

Comment: Why do you need to get it with Javascript? Why isn't the text already translated when it's being presented to the user? The only solution is to make an AJAX call like Dave already suggested.